# How do I clear the downloading indicator from a file in macOS?

Tags: finder

For some reason, one of the files I downloaded from the internet (which was fully downloaded without error) still appears in the Finder as if it is not done downloading:
[image: finder shows files still downloading]

How do I fix this so that I can see the size rather than the downloading indicator?

Here is the information I can get from `ls`:

```
user$ ls -lOe@ downloaded\ file\ shows\ as\ downloading.txt 
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  - 3285 Mar 11 16:59 downloaded file shows as downloading.txt
```

Things I have already tried:

- `xattr -d` successfully removed the `quarantine` and `kMDItemWhereFroms` attributes, but did not clear the downloading status.
- Duplicating the file works in that the duplicate file does not have this issue, but that is cheating. I want to know how to fix the original file.

#### Update

The indicator did go away after I rebooted the computer. I'd still like to know if there is an easier way.

Comment: Can you open Terminal and run `ls -l` in the folder containing the file? Please paste the result into the question (only the lines relating to "downloaded file").

Comment: @nohillside I added the output of `ls` as you requested

Comment: Does the issue persist if you reboot the system or before rebooting try `killall Finder` in Terminal? Also, what version of  macOS are you running?

Comment: It might be easier to understand what's going on if you show as the real file name, and run `ls -lOe@ realname*`.

Comment: @nohillside I don't know what you mean by `show as the real filename`. The real filename of the file is `downloaded file shows as downloading.txt` and adding a `*` at the end of the name in `ls` does not change the output.

Comment: Ah, try `downloaded*` then :-)

Comment: I'm talking about the original name of the file you've downloaded. Would be surprised if this was called `downloaded file shows as downloading.txt`.